# Finding domain of variables in joint density for marginal density

Tags: statistics, density-function

Let $(X,Y)$ have joint density $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(1+x+y)$ for $0<x<1$ and $0<y<1$.

So the joint density of $X$ and $U=X+Y$ is $f_{X,U}(x,u)=\frac{1}{2}(1+u)$. Now it is simple to get the domain of $X$ since it is provided in the problem description, but to get the domain of $U$ seems so be trickier since you need to extract the case of $U<1$ and $U\geq 1$. I need these values in order to get the marginal densities, but I am not quite sure what I need to do after I get $0<U-X<1$.

Comment: $0 < U - X < 1 \implies X < U < 1+X$, then $\because 0< X < 1 \therefore 0 < X < U < 1 + X < 1 + 1 = 2$, which is just the intuitive $0< U < 2$

Comment: Range of $U$ will depend on $X$ values. You can't write $U$ values independent of X.

Comment: @LeeDavidChungLin So then I got the two cases $U-1 < X < 1$ and $0<X<U$. Are those correct?

Comment: The domain of $U$ is $[0,2]$, it is true and it is the basic understanding of the situation. The joint domain of $f_{XU}$ is a parallelogram above the diagonal with vertices $(x,u)=(0, 0),\, (0,1),\,(1,2),\,(1,0)$. Yes like you said to split into 2 cases, the marginal $f_U$ from $f_{XU}$ is $(1+u)/2 \cdot (u-0) = u(1+u)/2$ from $X<U$ and $(1+u)/2 \cdot (1- (u-1)) = (2-u)(1+u)/2$ from $U-1 < X < 1$.

Comment: The $(u-0)$ is the horizontal segment length in the lower half of the parallelogram, from the two end points of $0 < X < U$, and the $(1 - (u-1))$ is the horizontal segment length in the upper triangular half of the parallelogram, from the two end points of $U-1 < X < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of $(X,U)$ is a parallelogram in $\mathbf{R}^2$: $X$ is in $(0,1)$, while $U$ is in $(X,X+1)$.